# JAVA Spring Boot : How to access application.properties values in normal class

Tags: java, spring-boot, class

I know how I can access the `application.properties` values in `@Service` classes in Java Spring boot like below

```
@Service
public class AmazonClient {

    @Value("${cloud.aws.endpointUrl}")
    private String endpointUrl;
}
```

But I am **looking for an option to access this value directly in any class** (a class without @Service annotation)

e.g.

```
public class AppUtils {
      @Value("${cloud.aws.endpointUrl}")
      private String endpointUrl;
}
```

But this returns `null`. Any help would be appreciated.
I have already read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30528255/8874958) but didn't help.

Comment: maybe `@Autowired private Environment env;`? I know it's not the same, but...

Comment: @Berto99 tried already but didn't work!

Comment: have u tried by annotating @Component on the class?

Comment: @SudiptaRoy can you show me a sample code?

Comment: If the AppUtils class have strict dependency on the endpointUrl and there are more such properties, I would suggest you create a bean of properties and then pass it to the constructor of AppUtils through your component or service, because there spring will inject the bean for you.

Comment: Please refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24649062/spring-read-property-value-from-properties-file-in-static-field-of-class/39368399

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50940314/8874958 also helped a lot. Thank you @tusharwason

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's no "magic" way to inject values from a property file into a class that isn't a bean. You can define a static `java.util.Properties` field in the class,  load values from the file manually when the class is loading and then work with this field:

```
public final class AppUtils {
    private static final Properties properties;

    static {
        properties = new Properties();

        try {
            ClassLoader classLoader = AppUtils.class.getClassLoader();
            InputStream applicationPropertiesStream = classLoader.getResourceAsStream("application.properties");
            applicationProperties.load(applicationPropertiesStream);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // process the exception
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked. But everytime when any function called from AppUtils class, then I am accessing like this properties.getProperty("cloud.aws.endpointUrl") , I hope this doesn't lead to memory leak

Comment: @KishanSolanki One follow up question, how would you create the `AppUtils` object in your code?

Comment: 1. This code doesn't lead to memory leak. The `static` block where we load properties from the file runs only once when this class is loaded by JVM. So if you start your application and use this class, the last one shouldn't be loaded again.

Comment: 2. We can add static methods to get property from this `property` field, and then call this method in code: `var propertyValue = AppUtils.getSomePropertyValue()`

Comment: @IgorAmelin there seems to be an error in the code provided, shouldn't it be properties.load(applicationPropertiesStream); instead? Also are you able to update your answer and include the static method you made mention of above?

Comment: But using this approach will potentially introduce bugs if you use `application-<profile>.properties` where Spring intelligently reads properties that are overridden based on what profile is loaded. In this suggested utility, it will only ever look in the root `application.properties` file.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily achieve this by annotating your app utils class with @component annotation. Spring will take care of loading properties.

But if you don't want to do that approach, then look at the link below.

https://www.baeldung.com/inject-properties-value-non-spring-class