# How to implement a data access layer within MVC Controller

Tags: c#, data-access-layer

I understand that data access layer's or simply DAL's are used to access and retrieve information from a database, but i'm not sure how to call the DAL data within the controller.
For instance i made this static class within my DAL but i'm not sure as to how to call it to my controller, any help or guideline would be appreciated. DohvatiMetodu is the name of the class.

```
public static FormInputViewModel DohvatiMetodu()
        {
            var viewModel = new FormInputViewModel();
            var metoda = new List<Metoda>();
            var metodaList = new List<SelectListItem>();

            using (var db = new ApplicationDbContext())
            {
                metoda = db.Metoda.ToList();
            }

            foreach (var metod in metoda)
            {
                metodaList.Add(new SelectListItem() {Value = metod.Id.ToString(), Text = metod.Naziv});
            }

            viewModel.KoristenaMetoda = metodaList;


            return viewModel;
```

Comment: DAL's are separate class files for performing CRUD operations on database. You can call the `StaticClass.MethodName()` from controller directly. There is no restriction in accessing DAL from controller nor does it break any rule in MVC.

Comment: If it's a static method, you just access it via `ClassName.MethodName` assuming you have the right namespace in scope. Of course, it's more common these days to not make things static, and instead use dependency injection to get the class into your controller.

Comment: Thank you for the info, but i'm interested as to how it would look like in the form of dependency injection?

Comment: Check below ans for that

Comment: Gaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa.  Don't write statics.  It makes it very hard to mock/unit test.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/153048/how-to-mock-with-static-methods/153067#153067

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per the many request of users I have updated code with full ***Repository Pattern*** step by step With Simple CRUD Methods:

*The Repository pattern adds a separation layer between the data and domain layers of an application. It also makes the data access parts of an application better testable.*

**Database Factory (IDatabaseFactory.cs):**

```
public interface IDatabaseFactory : IDisposable
{
    Database_DBEntities Get();
}
```

**Database Factory Implementations (DatabaseFactory.cs):**

```
public class DatabaseFactory : Disposable, IDatabaseFactory
{
    private Database_DBEntities dataContext;
    public Database_DBEntities Get()
    {
        return dataContext ?? (dataContext = new Database_DBEntities());
    }

    protected override void DisposeCore()
    {
        if (dataContext != null)
            dataContext.Dispose();
    }
}
```

**Base Interface (IRepository.cs):**

```
public interface IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    void Add(T entity);
    void Update(T entity);
    void Detach(T entity);
    void Delete(T entity);
    T GetById(long Id);
    T GetById(string Id);
    T Get(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where);
    IEnumerable<T> GetAll();
    IEnumerable<T> GetMany(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where);
    void Commit();
}
```

**Abstract Class (Repository.cs):**

```
 public abstract class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
    {
        private Database_DBEntities dataContext;
        private readonly IDbSet<T> dbset;
        protected Repository(IDatabaseFactory databaseFactory)
        {
            DatabaseFactory = databaseFactory;
            dbset = DataContext.Set<T>();

        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Property for the databasefactory instance
        /// </summary>
        protected IDatabaseFactory DatabaseFactory
        {
            get;
            private set;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Property for the datacontext instance
        /// </summary>
        protected Database_DBEntities DataContext
        {
            get { return dataContext ?? (dataContext = DatabaseFactory.Get()); }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// For adding entity
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="entity"></param>
        public virtual void Add(T entity)
        {

            try
            {
                dbset.Add(entity);
                //  dbset.Attach(entity);
                dataContext.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Added;
                int iresult = dataContext.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (UpdateException ex)
            {

            }
            catch (DbUpdateException ex) //DbContext
            {

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }

        }

        /// <summary>
        /// For updating entity
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="entity"></param>
        public virtual void Update(T entity)
        {
            try
            {
                // dbset.Attach(entity);
                dbset.Add(entity);
                dataContext.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
                int iresult = dataContext.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (UpdateException ex)
            {
                throw new ApplicationException(Database_ResourceFile.DuplicateMessage, ex);
            }
            catch (DbUpdateException ex) //DbContext
            {
                throw new ApplicationException(Database_ResourceFile.DuplicateMessage, ex);
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                throw ex;
            }
        }



        /// <summary>
        /// for deleting entity with class 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="entity"></param>
        public virtual void Delete(T entity)
        {
            dbset.Remove(entity);
            int iresult = dataContext.SaveChanges();
        }


        //To commit save changes
        public void Commit()
        {
            //still needs modification accordingly
            DataContext.SaveChanges();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Fetches values as per the int64 id value
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="id"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public virtual T GetById(long id)
        {
            return dbset.Find(id);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Fetches values as per the string id input
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="id"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public virtual T GetById(string id)
        {
            return dbset.Find(id);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// fetches all the records 
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public virtual IEnumerable<T> GetAll()
        {
            return dbset.AsNoTracking().ToList();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Fetches records as per the predicate condition
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="where"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public virtual IEnumerable<T> GetMany(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where)
        {
            return dbset.Where(where).ToList();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="entity"></param>
        public void Detach(T entity)
        {
            dataContext.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Detached;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// fetches single records as per the predicate condition
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="where"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public T Get(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where)
        {
            return dbset.Where(where).FirstOrDefault<T>();
        }

    }
```

**Now the main point is How to access this repository pattern in controller Here we go :**

**1. You have User Model :**

```
public partial class User
{
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

**2. Now you have to create Repository Class of your UserModel**

```
public class UserRepository : Repository<User>, IUserRepository
{
    private Database_DBEntities dataContext;

    protected IDatabaseFactory DatabaseFactory
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public UserRepository(IDatabaseFactory databaseFactory)
        : base(databaseFactory)
    {
        DatabaseFactory = databaseFactory;
    }

    protected Database_DBEntities DataContext
    {
        get { return dataContext ?? (dataContext = DatabaseFactory.Get()); }
    }

  public interface IUserRepository : IRepository<User>
  { 
  }
}
```

**3. Now you have to create UserService Interface (IUserService.cs) with all CRUD Methods :**

```
public interface IUserService
 {

     #region User Details 
     List<User> GetAllUsers();
     int SaveUserDetails(User Usermodel);
     int UpdateUserDetails(User Usermodel);
     int DeleteUserDetails(int Id);
     #endregion

}
```

**4. Now you have to create UserService Interface (UserService.cs) with all CRUD Methods :**

```
public class UserService : IUserService
{
  IUserRepository _userRepository;
  public UserService() { }
  public UserService(IUserRepository userRepository)
  {
   this._userRepository = userRepository;
  }
  public List<User> GetAllUsers()
  {
      try
      {
          IEnumerable<User> liUser = _userRepository.GetAll();
          return liUser.ToList();
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
          throw ex;
      }
  }
   /// <summary>
   /// Saves the User details.
   /// </summary>
   /// <param name="User">The deptmodel.</param>
   /// <returns></returns>
   public int SaveUserDetails(User Usermodel)
   {
       try
       {
           if (Usermodel != null)
           {
               _userRepository.Add(Usermodel);
               return 1;
           }
           else
               return 0;
       }
       catch
       {
           throw;
       }

   }

   /// <summary>
   /// Updates the User details.
   /// </summary>
   /// <param name="User">The deptmodel.</param>
   /// <returns></returns>
   public int UpdateUserDetails(User Usermodel)
   {
       try
       {
           if (Usermodel != null)
           {
               _userRepository.Update(Usermodel);
               return 1;
           }
           else
               return 0;
       }
       catch
       {
           throw;
       }
   }

   /// <summary>
   /// Deletes the User details.
   /// </summary>
   /// <param name="Id">The code identifier.</param>
   /// <returns></returns>
   public int DeleteUserDetails(int Id)
   {
       try
       {
           User Usermodel = _userRepository.GetById(Id);
           if (Usermodel != null)
           {
               _userRepository.Delete(Usermodel);
               return 1;
           }
           else
               return 0;
       }
       catch
       {
           throw;
       }
   }

}
```

**5. Now you All set for your Repository Pattern and you can access all data in User Controller :**

```
//Here is the User Controller 
public class UserProfileController : Controller
{

    IUserService _userservice;
    public CustomerProfileController(IUserService userservice)
    {
        this._userservice = userservice;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GetAllUsers(int id)
    {
    User objUser=new User();

    objUser = _userservice.GetAllUsers().Where(x => x.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();

    }
}
```

**Cheers !!**