# Code First Does not work

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, model-view-controller

I am trying to add code first,but the App_Data folder is empty.

**Web.config**

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-Movie-20170604111514.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-Movie-20170604111514;Integrated Security=True"
          providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="MovieDBContext" connectionString="Data Source=(localDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Movies.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
          providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" /> 
</connectionStrings>
```

**Model**

```
public class MovieDBContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Movie> Movies { get; set; }    
}
```

Can anyone help me ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This might not be important but you're using `Movies.pdf` instead of `Movies.mdf`

Comment: Thanks @dcg ,i already correct that,but it does not solve the problem.

Comment: You nee to check this ans : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44070400/how-to-implement-a-data-access-layer-within-mvc-controller/44070806#44070806

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a constructor in your **MovieDBContext** class as following:

```
public class MovieDBContext : DbContext
{
    public MovieDBContext () : base("Name=MovieDBContext")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Movie> Movies { get; set; }    
}
```

For more detail you can read following link:
http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/entity-framework-code-first.aspx

Comment: Please follow the link I shared with you, it has all the details step by step. It will help you

Comment: Can you please share the error details you are getting.

Comment: @Harsha Sharma there are no errors, the App_Data folder is just empty.